# Code Golf easy One line for statement for one time skip

Tags: python

I wanna first time skip
but many count. im Stupid.

```
count = 0
for a in articles:
    if count == 0:
        count += 1
        continue
    data = a.b.c()
    etc = a.abcde(E)
    # ~~~~..........
```

completed code

```
for c,l in enumerate(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(NS_URL, timeout=3).text, 'lxml').find_all('li')):    
    if c == 0: continue
    link = l.a.get('href')
    title = l.h1.a.text
    img = l.img.get('src')
```

new code

```
for l in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(NS_URL, timeout=3).text, 'lxml').find_all('li'))[1:]:
    link = l.a.get('href')
    title = l.h1.a.text
    img = l.img.get('src')
```

i use articles[1:].
thx tdelaney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make sure `articles` is an iterator and use `next` to discard one.

```
i_articles = iter(articles)
next(i_articles)
for a in i_articles:
    data = a.b.c()
```

or use `itertools` to slice the sequence much like `somelist[1::]`.

```
for a in itertools.islice(articles, 1, None, 1):
    data = a.b.c.()
```

Comment: bat import itertools ;D

Comment: You may not even need `itertools`, depending on what `articles` is. You could try `for a in articles[1:]: ...` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over the items and count them, use the `enumerate()` function:

```
for count, a in enumerate(articles):
    if count == 0:
        continue
    # now do whatever
```

Comment: Yes! Easy and Simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap "articles" with "enumerate" that will also return an index (increasing sequence). You can then call "continue" if index is 0:

```
articles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for i, a in enumerate(articles):
    if not i: continue
    # do something with a
    print(a)
```